# Change cell to clear content of other cells

Tags: vba, excel

i want to clear the cells in column C D E if date change in column B
but only cells in same row where date is changed (Date =Sheet1!c2) so date is from sheet 1 but from different cells and different rows 
[Sample xls file](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc12/24886/zzz-xlsm-15k)

This is what i did but its not working until manually change date in Column B sheet 2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b1:b100")) Is Nothing Then 
    Cells(Target.Row, 3) = "" 
    Cells(Target.Row, 4) = "" 
    Cells(Target.Row, 5) = "" 
End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at the Worksheet_Change event and its Target parameter.

Comment: @Doug Glancy this is what i did but its not working until manually change date in Column C sheet 2                                                            Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b1:b100")) Is Nothing Then


Cells(Target.Row, 3) = ""
Cells(Target.Row, 4) = ""
Cells(Target.Row, 5) = ""
End If
End Sub

Comment: Because the dates in column **B** are entered via *formula* you will need to use the *Calculate* event to catch the changes.

Comment: Also need to disable the events so it's not triggered with every change to columns D, E & F. Use `Application.EnableEvents = 0` then `Application.EnableEvents = 1` when finished.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent i am not expert can you please write that calculate event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an extremely simple, limited, example.  We are only monitoring cell **B5** which contains a formula.  The formula retrieves a date from another worksheet:

[image]

In the worksheet code area for this sheet we install the following Event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Dim Monitor As Range, Helper As Range
   Dim rw As Long
   Set Monitor = Range("B5")
   Set Helper = Range("H5")
   rw = Monitor.Row

   Application.EnableEvents = False
      If Helper.Value = "" Then
            Helper.Value = Monitor.Value
      Else
         If Helper.Value <> Monitor.Value Then
            Helper.Value = Monitor.Value
            Range("C" & rw & ":E" & rw).ClearContents
         End If
      End If
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The code uses cell **H5** as a "helper"  The first time the code runs, the helper cell is filled.  Each time after that, the code compares the "helper" against **H5**.  If they become different, cells **C** thru **E** in that row are cleared.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1:**

Completely discard the original macro and install this one instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Dim Monitor As Range, Helper As Range
   Dim rw As Long, r As Range
   Set Monitor = Range("B2:B100")
   Set Helper = Range("H2:H100")


   Application.EnableEvents = False
      For Each r In Helper
         If r.Value = "" Then
            r.Value = r.Offset(0, -6).Value
         End If
      Next r

      For Each r In Helper
         If r.Value <> r.Offset(0, -6).Value Then
            r.Value = r.Offset(0, -6).Value
            rw = r.Row
            Range("C" & rw & ":E" & rw).ClearContents
         End If
      Next r
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

As you see, we must loop over each item in the ranges.

Comment: can i make this like that Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Dim Monitor As Range, Helper As Range
   Dim rw As Long
   Set Monitor = Range("B1:B10")
   Set Helper = Range("H1:H10")
   rw = Monitor.Row

   Application.EnableEvents = False
      If Helper.Value = "" Then
            Helper.Value = Monitor.Value
      Else
         If Helper.Value <> Monitor.Value Then
            Helper.Value = Monitor.Value
            Range("C" & rw & ":E" & rw).ClearContents
         End If
      End If
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Comment: i code you write is working perfect but only on one cell change event that is B5 but i have a full column of dates

Comment: Dates are in B2 to B100

Comment: i try to change ur code as Range("B2:B100") but its not working

Comment: Yes it is working Perfect only first time i have to change date twice

Comment: @KzhelFarmer  First time change date to setup *Helper* ..................second time change date to trigger the clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using the `Worksheet_Change` *Event* (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn301178.aspx)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Column = 2 Then

            Rem Disable Events. So it's not triggered by changes to columns D, E & F
            Application.EnableEvents = 0

            Rem Clear Columns D, E & F same row
            .Cells.Offset(, 2).ClearContents
            .Cells.Offset(, 3).ClearContents
            .Cells.Offset(, 4).ClearContents

            Rem Enable Events after changes
            Application.EnableEvents = 1

    End If: End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i just copied and paste ur full code in sheet 2 no effect

Comment: It seems that events are off
Try this is a module 
`Sub App_EnableEvents` 
`Application.EnableEvents = 1` 
`end sub`